# Open recently closed page on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch, mobile-safari

I know on iPad you can press and hold the new tab button to re-open recently closed tabs, but is there any similar functionality on an iPod/iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hate to provide what is effectively a 1 word answer, but no.

Because iPhone Safari does not use tabs, the shortcut/gesture is missing.  Going into the '`other pages`' screen and tapping and holding all over yeilds nothing.  Simply not available using Safari.

You may have more luck with a 3rd party browser if it's an important bit of functionality to have.

Comment: Alright, that's what I thought. Problem is all the 3rd party browsers are rated 18+, but I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reopen the last closed page Safari iOS iPhone/iPod directly.

But you can still use the history to retrieve recently visited pages.